# no fine_tune_checkpoint field in pipeline.config

Tags: tensorflow-model-garden

I want to fine tune **CenterNet MobileNetV2 FPN Keypoints 512x512** for object detection from: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2_detection_zoo.md .
I dowloaded the tar and extracted.
The **pipeline.config** doen not have **fine_tune_checkpoint** field, so I am not able to fine tune on pretrained model.
I have two questions:-
Is there any way to add the field for fine tuning?
Is it because the output of this model is keypoints?

Answer (score 1):

That field is defined as an optional in [train.proto](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/6b8bb0cbeb3e10415c7a87448f08adc3c484c1d3/research/object_detection/protos/train.proto#L41), so you can still use it.

In this case, it would be written as follows.(path of the folder should match your environment)

> fine_tune_checkpoint: "centernet_mobilenetv2_fpn_kpts/checkpoint/ckpt-301"